# The app is closed when I click the button

Tags: android

Hi this is my first question here.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.kerry.chellenge04;        
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {        
    EditText name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
    public void button(View view){
        String string=name.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }    
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="346dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="button"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="58dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="401dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It's very simple code. When I press the button, the app is supposed to show you what you typed in edittext, but it stops. Can you guys please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: set android:id="@+id/text" to your `EditText` in `activity_main.xml`

Comment: No Id for EditText. Please give it ID

Comment: Where is id for `text`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one
You need to assign an id to your **EditText**:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="288dp"
    android:layout_height="346dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
```

Comment: wow it works after I modified. I put Id on design tab and I thought It's weird that there is no id in text. I should've tried adding it beforehand thank you so much

Comment: @KerryLee Thank you, Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an id to your `EditText`:

```
android:id="@+id/text"
```

otherwise this line:

```
name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

will assign `null` to `name`.
So when you try to access any property or method of the object `name`
a **Null Pointer Exception** will be thrown and your app will crash.

Comment: wow it works after I modified. I put Id on design tab and I thought It's weird that there is no id in text. I should've tried adding it beforehand thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you should you the activity context rather than the application context.
try to replace

`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

with

`Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

then, as already said, you should add the id, but I believe you did, as you can access the generated R.id.text